# Getting the value of the key from json in java script(storing the key name in a variable and using it)

Tags: javascript, json

So in java script i need to get the value of a key from the json. But if i give object dot name of the key then am able to get it.

```
<script>
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.employees[1].firstname + " " + obj.employees[1].lastName;
</script>
```

But if i store the name of the key in a variable and use it to get  the value of the key then it is not working for me.

```
<script>
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
fn="firstname";
ln="lastname";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.employees[1].fn + " " + obj.employees[1].ln;
</script>
```

I can understand the problem that it is looking for the key with fn and ln. Can anyone explain me how can i get the value of the key using variable in which the key name is stored.

Comment: use bracket notation to access the values in this case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: It should be `firstName` and not `firstname`. Note that `n` is capitalized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to elaborate a little more on the reason why your code doesn't run properly. This is because of the way that JavaScript interprets what comes after the dot notation.

```
fn="firstName";
obj.employees[1].fn;
```

In this case, obj.employees[1].fn would return undefined, because JavaScript is looking for a property on obj called "fn", despite fn being the name of a variable. However, using a bracket notation "unboxes" the string stored in the variable, and uses that to grab the property key. Like mentioned in the other answer, the proper way to grab a key with a dynamic variable is by using bracket notation.

```
obj.employees[0][fn];
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var obj = JSON.parse( '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}')

var fn = "firstName";
var ln = "lastName";

console.log(obj.employees[0][fn]);
console.log(obj.employees[0][ln]);
```

They can be accessed like this:

```
firstname = obj.employees[1][fn]  
lastname = obj.employees[1][ln]
```